# A (intense) pulsed field?

Tags: indefinite-article

So, I just came across a sentence in a summary I'm writing, where something has me stumped:

Consider the sentence: "A (intense) pulsed field is applied."

If I just wrote "A pulsed field is applied.", that would of course be correct. Same with "An intense field is applied". As *intense* starts with a vowel, *an* is used.

But what would I use in the context that intense is a not-so-important quality of the field? I could write "an intense pulsed field"; but want to convey that the pulsed character is more important, and the intensity is secondary. Does setting *intense* in parentheses call for *a* because it refers to pulsed? This does of course generalize to other descriptive adjectives that start with a vowel and consonant, respectively.

For context, this is a homework assignment for a physics lecture.

Comment: Not sure if a duplicate because on another community, but this should help: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/a-an-preceding-a-parenthetical-statement

Comment: That explains it perfectly!