# Should we use a/an before a bracket starting with a vowel?

Tags: grammar, articles, punctuation

I want to say "It's being discussed because there is **a** (almost certainly fake) rumour about it."

I learned that we should put "an" if the next word starts with a vowel, but in this sentence the bracket is an optional part of the sentence so I'm not sure.

Should I use "an" instead of "a"?

Comment: The brackets don't affect the pronunciation, so it's _an_ as though the bracket wasn't there.

Comment: Alternative ways of setting off parenthetical matter, such as commas, or em dashes,  likewise don't count for the purpose of deciding whether to use 'a' or 'an'. Also whether in speech to say 'thee' or 'thuh' (although quite a lot of people don't observe this these days).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments:

The brackets don't affect the pronunciation, so it's *an* as though the bracket wasn't there.

Also:

Alternative ways of setting off parenthetical matter, such as commas, or em dashes, likewise don't count for the purpose of deciding whether to use 'a' or 'an'.

Furthermore, see this related question: [A (intense) pulsed field?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/167263/a-intense-pulsed-field)